# Measurement conversions in PHP

Tags: php, converters

I'm trying to do a PHP converter that convert measurements with basic and simple code as possible (new to this). I hope this image will help you understand what I'm trying to do:

I have created a **HTML file** with a form that looks like this:

```
<form action="converter.php" method="post">
 <input type="text" name="number">
 <select name="choose">
        <option>Choose</option>
        <option value="meter" id="meter">Meter</option>
        <option value="cm" id="cm">Cm</option>
        <option value="foot" id="fot">Fot</option>
        <option value="inches" id="tum">Tum</option>
<input type="submit" value="Convert!">
</form>
```

And a **PHP file** that look like this, and it's not much but:

```
<?php    
$number = $_POST['number'];
$choose = $_POST['choose'];

$x = $number;    
echo "$number $choose  <br>";    
?>
```

Aaaand I'm stuck. I dont really know how to convert the values, both mathematically and in code. Doesn't matter if you give me the whole code or a hint of what to do next, just need a push in the right direction.

Thank you!

Comment: You probably are going to have to write a switch, depending on what you choose, and do different calculations based on the choice you made..

Comment: As @Thamizhan stated, firstly we need to know what unit your input is in. Meters? Cm?

Comment: **Or** is your dropdown a selection of the input type? Subsequently you want to convert the unit into all the other units?

Comment: Yes the dropdown is a selection of the unit type and then the "page" will have to convert that unit into all other units. But also display the answer of the original unit. So if I choose to convert 50 CM the answer will show how much 50 CM is in CM (yes, also that) and in meter, foot and inches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simpler one:

**index.html**

```
<form action="converter.php" method="post">
 <input type="number" name="number" required>
 <select name="choose">
        <option>Choose</option>
        <option value="meter" id="meter">Meter</option>
        <option value="cm" id="cm">Cm</option>
        <option value="foot" id="fot">Fot</option>
        <option value="inches" id="tum">Tum</option>
<input type="submit" value="Convert!">
</form>
```

**converter.php**

```
<?php
$number = $_POST['number'];
$choose = $_POST['choose'];

$meters = $number / ($choose == 'cm'? 100 : ($choose == 'foot'? 3.28084 : ($choose == 'inches'? 39.3701 : 1))); 

echo "Meters : $meters<br/>";
echo "Cm : ".($meters*100)."<br/>";
echo "Foot : ".($meters*3.28084)."<br/>";
echo "Inches : ".($meters*39.3701)."<br/>";
```

Comment: Are you sure the calculation on this solution is right?

Comment: If you have any doubt, check with your calculator

Comment: Well, if I choose to convert 1 cm it says that 1 cm is 100 meters

Comment: @Mordor sorry my mistake (misplaced * and / operators).. corrected

Answer (score 0):

Do the necessary calculations in the php file.

Note: Edited with the calculation, but never tested. Double check the calculations part.

**HTML**

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    //called when key is pressed in textbox
    $("#number").keypress(function (e) {
     //if the letter is not digit then display error and don\'t type anything
     if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
               return false;
    }
    });
});
</script>

<form action="converter.php" method="post">
 <input type="text" name="number" id="number">
 <select name="choose">
        <option>Choose</option>
        <option value="meter" id="meter">Meter</option>
        <option value="cm" id="cm">Cm</option>
        <option value="foot" id="fot">Fot</option>
        <option value="inches" id="tum">Tum</option>
<input type="submit" value="Convert!">
</form>
```

**converter.php**

```
<?php    
$number = isset($_POST['number']) ? $_POST['number'] : 0;
$choose = isset($_POST['choose']) ? $_POST['choose'] : '';

switch ($choose)
{
case 'meter':
    $cm      = $number * 100;
    $foot    = $number * 3.2808;
    $inches  = $number * 39.370;
    $Answer  = 'Meters: '.$number.'<br />'.
               'Cm: '.$cm.'<br />'.
               'Foot: '.$foot.'<br />'.
               'Inches: '.$inches;

break;

case 'cm':
    $meter   = $number / 100;
    $foot    = $number * 0.032808;
    $inches  = $number * 0.39370;
    $Answer  = 'Cm: '.$cm.'<br />'.
               'Meters: '.$number.'<br />'.            
               'Foot: '.$foot.'<br />'.
               'Inches: '.$inches;
break;

case 'foot':
    $meter   = $number / 3.2808;
    $cm      = $number / 0.032808;
    $inches  = $number * 12.000;
    $Answer  = 'Foot: '.$foot.'<br />'.
               'Meters: '.$number.'<br />'.
               'Cm: '.$cm.'<br />'.            
               'Inches: '.$inches;
break;

case 'inches':
    $meter   = $number / 39.370;
    $cm      = $number / 0.39370;
    $foot    = $number / 12.000;
    $Answer  = 'Inches: '.$inches.'<br />'.
               'Foot: '.$foot.'<br />'.
               'Meters: '.$number.'<br />'.
               'Cm: '.$cm;
break;
default:
    $Answer  = '';
break;
}

echo $Answer;
?>
```

Comment: wow! thank you! Can I ask why you have wrote this code in the beginning of the PHP file: 

$number = isset($_POST['number']) ? $_POST['number'] : 0;
$choose = isset($_POST['choose']) ? $_POST['choose'] : '';

Comment: Need to check whether the variable is set. Thats the better way of receiving the POST/GET variables

Comment: you  can use the above code and modify the calculation part if wrong

Comment: Thank You! I hope you dont mind me asking another Q: How do I make the form check/validate that the user have only used numbers (0-9) in the input field?

Comment: note: <input type="text" name="number" id="number">

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your input unit type all you'll be doing is guesswork. My advice would be to change the form to the following code for simpler input. Then it's a quick and simple division / multiplication to get the desired result. Here's a quick code sample for both form and php processing code.

There's a little more code to add to it, including the additional conversions and a quick check to see that certain values are set, but you should get the gist of it hopefully.

```
<form action="converter.php" method="post">
    <fieldset><legend>Select Your Input Type and Value</legend>
    <input type="number" name="inputNumber" step="any" value="" />
    <select name="inputFormat">
        <optgroup name="Choose">
        <option value="meter" id="meter">Meter</option>
        <option value="cm" id="cm">Cm</option>
        <option value="foot" id="fot">Fot</option>
        <option value="inches" id="tum">Tum</option>
        </optgroup>
    </select>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset><legend>Select your Output Type</legend>
    <select name="outputFormat">
        <optgroup name="Choose">
        <option value="meter" id="meter">Meter</option>
        <option value="cm" id="cm">Cm</option>
        <option value="foot" id="fot">Fot</option>
        <option value="inches" id="tum">Tum</option>
        </optgroup>
    </select>   
    </fieldset>     

    <input type="submit" name="submitForm" value="Convert!" />
</form>



<?php
$outputNumber=0;
$inputNumber = (float)$_POST['inputNumber'];
$inputFormat = $_POST['inputFormat'];
$outputFormat = $_POST['outputFormat'];

    switch($inputFormat){
    case "meter":

        switch ($outputFormat){
        case "meter": $outputNumber = $inputNumber;break;           //METER TO METER
        case "cm": $outputNumber = $inputNumber*100;break;          //METER TO CM
        case "foot": $outputNumber = $inputNumber*3.2808399;break;  //METER TO FT
        case "inches": $outputNumber = $inputNumber*39.3700787;break;//METER TO INCHES

        }

    break;

    case "cm":

    //ADD CONVERSION SWITCH IN HERE
    break;

    case "foot":

    //ADD CONVERSION SWITCH IN HERE
    break;

    case "inches":

    //ADD CONVERSION SWITCH IN HERE
    break;  
    }


echo $outputNumber;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please also update php code for these categories. `<select name="choose"><option>Choose</option><option value="kg" id="kg">kg</option><option value="liter" id="liter">Liter</option><option value="mililiter" id="mililiter">Mililiter</option></select>`

Answer (score 0):

The question is already answered, but for future sake I am writing this especially for those who will be be working on SI units conversion on a larger scale.

I wrote a PHP library for SI units conversion called puconverter , you just call a function and it converts it for you like this

```
 <?php
 include "puconverter.php";

echo length_converter($val,"cm", "m"); //this will convert $val in centimetres to its equivalent metres

  ?>
```

In your senerio using it to create a web app: the  SI unit arguments passed will be a variable holding the value of the name of the chosen unit in the HTML form, which in this case let's assume the value will be cm so use like this:

```
  if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
 $convertFrom= $_POST["centimeter"];
 $val= $_POST["value"];
//$val is value to convert, $convertFrom is unit of the value to be converted
echo length_converter($val $convertFrom,"m");//returns value in metres
 echo length_converter($val ,$convertFrom,"mm");//returns value in millimetres
 echo length_converter($val ,$convertFrom,"km");//returns value in kilometres
  }
```

For full documentation of all other SI unit conversion functions visit the library GitHub page:https://github.com/GeniusGeeek/pu-converter/blob/master/README.md